# Open saved png's by savefig to plot them in subplots

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, plot

I saved plots with savefig like `plt.savefig('1.png')` and now I want to adjust them to determined subplots like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("1.png")

img1 = Image.open("2.png")

img1 = Image.open("3.png")


fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1,
                          sharex=True, figsize=(8.27,11.7))

ax_1.set_title('Plot1')
ax_1 = img1

ax_2.set_title('Plot2')
ax_2 = img2

ax_3.set_title('Plot3')
ax_3 = img3

fig.suptitle('Name')
plt.show()
```

But I get 3 empty plots without an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`ax.imshow()`](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imshow.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from PIL import Image

img1 = Image.open("1.png")

img1 = Image.open("2.png")

img1 = Image.open("3.png")


fig, (ax_1, ax_2, ax_3) = plt.subplots(nrows=3, ncols=1,
                          sharex=True, figsize=(8.27,11.7))

ax_1.set_title('Plot1')
ax_1.imshow(img1)

ax_2.set_title('Plot2')
ax_2.imshow(img2)

ax_3.set_title('Plot3')
ax_3.imshow(img3)

fig.suptitle('Name')
plt.show()
```

If you want to remove the ticks and tick labels, you can add `ax.axis('off')` for every axis you to remove them.